# Find the element in $\mathbb{Z}/143\mathbb{Z}$ whose image is $(\overline{10},\overline{11})$ under the Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Find the element in $\mathbb{Z}/143\mathbb{Z}$ whose image is $(\overline{10},\overline{11})$ in $\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/13\mathbb{Z}$ under the Chinese remainder theorem

---

So I figured we must find an element $\overline{x}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/143\mathbb{Z}$ that satisfies:

$x \equiv 10  \pmod {11} $

$x \equiv 11  \pmod {13} $

Applying the Chinese remainder theorem gives us $x=76$.

Can I then simply conclude that the element we're looking for in $\mathbb{Z}/143\mathbb{Z}$ is $\overline{76}$?

Comment: How did you get $54$? $54 \equiv 2 \not\equiv 11 \mod 13$

Comment: Sorry, it should be $76$. Wasn't looking at the same question when I entered the $54$.

Comment: As far as I know the Chinese Remainder Theorem is not constructive. How did you calculate $76$?

Comment: @McFry, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html

Comment: In that case it says right there that the number you get is the number you want.

Answer (score 1):

Solving the CRT by substitution directly, we have:
$$\begin{align}
x &=11k+10 \\
11k+10 &\equiv 11 \bmod 13 \\
11k &\equiv 1 \bmod 13 \\
k &\equiv  11^{-1} \bmod 13 \\
\end{align}$$

Then it's easy to find $11^{-1} = 6 \pmod {13}$ (since $66\equiv 1 \bmod 13$), and thus $k=6$ and $x=76 \;\square$.

And yes, that's the residue class that satisfies your initial problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Find an element $x$ with $x\equiv1\pmod {11}$ and $x\equiv0\pmod {13}.$ Similarly find $y$ with $\begin{cases}y\equiv0\pmod{11}\\y\equiv1\pmod {13}\end{cases}.$ Then $10x+11y\pmod{143}$ is what you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't really my question. I know how to solve these equations, but I don't know if I can just simply conclude from that that the answer is $\overline{54}$.

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: Yes, the answer here is what you found, $\overline{54}$.

Answer (score 0):

By Bezout's identity we know that we can find $ x, y$ such that $ 11x + 13y = 1 $. Using the Euclidean algorithm, we have:

$$ 13 = 11\cdot 1 + 2 $$
$$ 11 = 2 \cdot 5 + 1 $$
$$ 2 = 2 \cdot 1 + 0 $$

and now we substitute back:

$$ 1 = 11 - 2 \cdot 5 = 11 - (13 - 11) \cdot 5 = 11 \cdot 6 - 13 \cdot 5 $$

This helps us because now we can explicitly produce the solution. Indeed, I claim that the solution is $ 11 \cdot 6 \cdot 11 - 13 \cdot 5 \cdot 10 = 76 $. We have that

$$ 11 \cdot 6 \cdot 11 - 13 \cdot 5 \cdot 10 \equiv 11 \cdot 6 \cdot 10 - 13 \cdot 5 \cdot 10 \equiv 10 \pmod{11} $$

and

$$ 11 \cdot 6 \cdot 11 - 13 \cdot 5 \cdot 10 \equiv 11 \cdot 6 \cdot 10 - 13 \cdot 5 \cdot 11 \equiv 11 \pmod{13} $$

Generally, if $ I $ and $ J $ are comaximal ideals of a ring $ R $, we can find $ i \in I $ and $ j \in J $ such that $ i + j = 1_R $. Then, the expression $ bi + aj $ lies in the cosets $ a + I $ and $ b + J $. In the case that $ R $ is an Euclidean domain, the Euclidean algorithm gives an easy way of computing $ i $ and $ j $ explicitly.